# In Linux, how do you learn about newly acquired child processes before they exit?

Tags: c, linux, process, pid

I'm writing a program that calls `prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, 1)`. So, it might acquire processes that it knows nothing about when their parents exit. I would like this process to exit when all of it's children have exited, including the ones it became the parent of because they would've been orphans otherwise.

How do I do this in a reasonable way from a C or C++ program? I don't want to have to be opening up everything in `/proc` all the time or calling out to a process that does that for me. That's a polling solution anyway, and I would prefer a solution that didn't involve polling.

Also, ptracing all of the children to find out when they call `fork` isn't really an option either. Just in case someone had that bright idea.

Comment: Could you clarify why you need to know about the newly acquired child processes? It sounds like you want to wait for them, but it's not necessary to know what they are in order to wait for them.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Because, in classic fashion, I wasn't asking the right question. I was asking a question that pre-supposed an approach to solving my problem. Something people commonly do, unfortunately. It is, in fact, often the main obstacle many people (including me this time) have to solving their problem.

Comment: Color me confused, it sounds like the original question has the answer you were looking for and the "before they exit" version of the question doesn't.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Well, they exit after they're acquired. So, learning about a process that has exited already is learning about it after it's newly acquired. I acquire the child process, at which point it's newly acquired, and then it exits. Of course, I might've acquired a zombie, in which case it's already exited, but.. I still hope that deconfuses you about what I thought I was asking.

Comment: That’s not necessarily what happens. You can acquire a process after it exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything fancy with `/proc`.  Just use `wait()`.  From the man page:

> PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER (since Linux 3.4)
>
> If arg2 is nonzero, set the "child subreaper" attribute of the calling process; if arg2 is zero, unset the attribute.  When a
>   process is
>      marked  as  a  child  subreaper,  all  of the children that it creates, and their descendants, will be marked as having a
>   subreaper.  In
>      effect, a subreaper fulfills the role of init(1) for its descendant processes.  **Upon termination of a process that  is 
>   orphaned  (i.e.,
>      its  immediate parent has already terminated) and marked as having a subreaper, the nearest still living ancestor subreaper will
>   receive
>      a SIGCHLD signal and be able to wait(2) on the process to discover its termination status.**

So your process just needs sit in a loop calling `wait` until it returns -1 with `errno` being set to `ECHILD`.  This will happen when *all* processes in the process tree have exited.  You don't need to know when you acquire new child process to wait for as long as you do this.

Suppose you have the following process tree with process 1000 being the reaper:

```
1000
  |---1001
  |     |---1002
  |     |---1003
  |
  |---1004
        |---1005
        |---1006
```

When you first call `wait`, both 1001 and 1004 need to exit before it returns -1.  Now suppose 1004 exits:

```
1000
  |---1001
  |     |---1002
  |     |---1003
  |
  |---1004 (dead)
  |-----|---1005
  |-----|---1006
```

In the reaper, `wait` returns 1004.  Now 1001, 1005, and 1006 need to exit.  Next, 1002 exits:

```
1000
  |---1001
  |     |---1002 (zombie)
  |     |---1003
  |
  |---1004 (dead)
  |-----|---1005
  |-----|---1006
```

The reaper doesn't return from `wait` yet because 1001 is still running and can still `wait` for 1002.  At this point, 1002 is a zombie.  Next, 1001 calls `wait`:

```
1000
  |---1001
  |     |---1002 (dead)
  |     |---1003
  |
  |---1004 (dead)
  |-----|---1005
  |-----|---1006
```

No change to what the reaper is expecting since 1002 was waited for by 1001.  Then 1005 exits:

```
1000
  |---1001
  |     |---1002 (dead)
  |     |---1003
  |
  |---1004 (dead)
  |-----|---1005 (dead)
  |-----|---1006
```

`wait` in the reaper returns 1005 and now needs 1001 and 1006 to exit.  Then 1003 exits:

```
1000
  |---1001
  |     |---1002 (dead)
  |     |---1003 (zombie)
  |
  |---1004 (dead)
  |-----|---1005 (dead)
  |-----|---1006
```

Again, no change to what the reaper is expecting.  Now 1001 exits:

```
1000
  |---1001 (dead)
  |     |---1002 (dead)
  |-----|---1003 (dead)
  |
  |---1004 (dead)
  |-----|---1005 (dead)
  |-----|---1006
```

Now `wait` in the reaper returns twice in a row, once returning 1001 and once returning 1003.  Now the reaper is waiting for only 1006.  Once that exits:

```
1000
  |---1001 (dead)
  |     |---1002 (dead)
  |-----|---1003 (dead)
  |
  |---1004 (dead)
  |-----|---1005 (dead)
  |-----|---1006 (dead)
```

`wait` in the reaper returns 1006, and the next call returns -1 ending the loop.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to know _before_ the new child has exited? I want to know if I should keep waiting around for children to exit, or exit myself.

Comment: @Omnifarious: That's very different from the question you were asking. But if you look at the manual for `wait`, you'll see that it will return immediately with `ECHILD` if there is nothing to wait for, at which point you are done.

Comment: @Omnifarious You should *always* keep waiting.  If there's nothing left to wait for, `wait` returns -1.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Well, I don't think it's different, though I clarified my question. I thought I was clear enough when I said "newly acquired'. But apparently not. :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious: As I understand the question, you asked how to wait for all child processes exit in a process which is a subreaper. This is different from figuring out when you acquire new children as a subreaper.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Yes. And, in fact, the question you thought I was asking was, in fact, a better question to ask for my purposes. But it wasn't the question I meant to ask. :-) The correct answer to my question is (I think): "You can't. But you can find out if the last child has exited because the various forms of wait will return an error and errno will be set to ECHILD.".

Comment: @dbush - If you'll change your answer to be about ECHILD, I'll vote it up and accept it. :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious I added more detail and some examples.

Comment: @dbush - Way better than I was expecting, and an excellent thing for people who happen upon this question to find. Thank you.

Comment: @Omnifarious: If I understood your comments correctly, you *can* use [`waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to check if there are child processes left (and if a child process happens to have exited, reap it/one). It will always return immediately (and not block). It too will return `-1` with `errno == ECHILD` if there are no children left.

Comment: @NominalAnimal - Yep. I happen to be using `waitid`. But, same idea. I've already fixed my program to do this. :-)

Comment: This answer is problematic because any use of `wait` (or `waitpid` or `waitid` with a pid argument of -1) makes it impossible to safely use `fork`, `posix_spawn`, `popen`, etc. in your program. You can only safely wait on an already-known pid. Fixing this problem probably requires clever use of `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: @R.. You could get the pid from `SIGCHLD` if you use `sigaction`, but you still have to `wait`.  As long as you don't depend on calling `waitpid` with a nonnegative first parameter you won't miss anything.

Comment: @dbush: Any correct use of child processses you are aware of (or that the implementation is aware of, as in `popen`) **does require calling `waitpid` (or `waitid`) with nonnegative first parameter**. That's why it's a hard problem. You might be able to segregate indirect descendants by pgid or something, though, and thereby identify them at `SIGCHLD` time and only wait on them if they're not in your pgid.

Comment: @R.. How does using `wait` interfere with the operation of `fork`?  I didn't see anything in the man pages that suggests it could be an issue.

Comment: @R.. - I am also curious. It sounds like you have some very specific problems in mind, and I don't understand what they are. Why isn't it safe to call waitid with -1 as an argument?

Comment: @Omnifarious: it may be safe if nothing will ever attempt to use pids you may unknowingly reap. Otherwise it's a use-after-free bug. Pids are resource identifiers whose lifetime ends when you wait on them.

Comment: To make a concrete example, suppose `popen` creates process 123, then your `wait` call consumes pid 123. At some point in the future, you end up with a new child (maybe due to being a subreaper, maybe one you created yourself) with pid 123. Now you call `pclose`, and while it should return immediately, it deadlocks waiting for the new pid 123 to terminate.

Comment: Things get much worse if you use pids with `kill`.

Comment: @R.. - Ahh. That does make sense. And for me, this will not be a problem for my case. I call no other code that would care about process ids. Though, there is a flag you can give waitid (`WNOWAIT`) that will let you poke some other wait mechanism that knows about the particular process ids it's waiting for. This basically means that any part of the system that creates process ids it cares about needs to somehow register with a central mechanism if you're acting as an init process that has to reap all of its children.